# My school have monitored my emails - I sent a distasteful email. Can I get in trouble?

Tags: united-kingdom, criminal-law, email

I live in the UK.
I recently sent an email to a group of my friends (only close friends) about an incident that has happened recently at my school through the school email (which operates through Outlook).

A member of staff has been arrested on suspicion of a crime (that I don't wish to mention) and is under continuing investigation. I mentioned this incident in a joke in this email.

The school have sinced tracked this email down - they've been monitoring emails for keywords since this case - and have now started questioning me about it.
What should I do? I fear this could have some serious implications - could I get in legal trouble or will it have to be maintained within the school?
Thanks!

Comment: Can you elaborate on the contents of the e-mail? I know freedom of speech works a bit differently across the pond, but I assume you'd have to be saying something dangerous to get in legal trouble. Of course - getting expelled from a school may not be a legal matter at all. If that's what you're worried about, consult your school's policies.

Comment: The email didn't include hate crime, racism or anything of the sort. It was specific to the incident at my school - I don't think it was dangerous enough to be a legal matter if that's all I have to worry about. I'll look at my school's policies. Thanks!

Comment: Just because you think it doesn't warrant legal intervention doesn't mean it can't have consequences.  The school may have policies they argue it contradicts and try to punish or expel you, which can have serious long-term life consequences.  The school may be afraid of publicity around the staff member or may be questioning you to find out where you got your information.  Your best bet is probably to show the email to someone authorized to practice law there who actually knows the ins and outs of dealing with the school system in the UK.  There's no substitute for experience.

Comment: A parent who is a good advocate may also be able to help you deal with them, but it depends on the parent.  Hopefully the school is either competent or just trying to keep the matter quiet, either of which discourages it from doing anything to significant to punish you unless the email is worse than you say.  But better safe than sorry.

Comment: With regard to the law itself, you should perhaps educate yourself about what does and does not constitute *defamation*  (loosely, that means making a *false* statement that damages someone else's reputation).  If your statement about the member of staff allows room for doubt that you necessarily believe him/her to be guilty, or if you merely mention that their guilt has been *alleged* by someone else, then your statement is usually quite defensible.  But do remember, as has been pointed out in these comments, that schools are free to impose their own rules in addition to the law of the land.

Comment: Depends on the nature of the e-mail. It could be very "jokey", but @jez has explained how it could be construed defamation. If you're worried about school consequences then remember that they're just teachers, overpaid babysitters, and nobody cares what they think. Speak with the Head and only the Head on the matter - that person should have real management responsibility and understand the consequences of someone "going to the press" should they decide to attack you in any way. Don't let any teachers bully you.

Comment: @jez: I believe that the legal crimes of defamation, namely libel and slander, do not require the statement to be false in the UK. (There was a law passed recently in the US to block enforcement of UK defamation rulings that did not meet the US rule, specifically as individuals were "docket shopping" for UK courts, were the plaintiff does not have to prove falsehood and truth is not a defense).

Comment: @sharur Truth *is* a defense under the Defamation Act of 2013 but the *burden* of proof of truth is on the defendant (which makes the UK a desirable "libel tourism" destination, although this was even worse before the 2013 Act)